# Applying UDF only on rows where value is not null or not an empty string not working as expected

Tags: python-3.x, pyspark, user-defined-functions

What's the best (fastest) way to apply an UDF only when a value is not null or not an empty string.

I've added a simple example.

```py
df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [["John Jones"], ["Tracey Smith"], [None], ["Amy Sanders"], [""]]
).toDF("Name")


def upperCase(str):
    return str.upper()


upperCaseUDF = udf(lambda z: upperCase(z), StringType())

df.withColumn(
    "Cureated Name",
    F.when(
        ((F.col("Name").isNotNull()) | (F.trim(F.col("name")) != "")),
        upperCaseUDF(F.col("Name")),
    ),
)

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'upper'.
```

I don't think the when clause works properly (or at least not as I would expect).
I get an error for the Null value.

I expect the UDF not to be executed on a Null value.
It's not about solving the Null value, but why the when clause doesn't work as I would expect !

Comment: Your problem lies with ```upperCaseUDF = udf(lambda z:upperCase(z),StringType())''', since you have an attribute with a value of ```None``.  NoneType has no attribute '''upper()''.  You can fix this easily by  updating the function ```upperCase``  to detect a None value and return something, else return value.upper()

Comment: @itprorh66
As stated I understand the error but why is the UDF applied while there's a Null value? It looks like the when clause is ignored. I don't wan't to check for Null values in the UDF, just not applying the UDF when the value is Null or an empty string

Comment: I think that the optimizer, in order to save computation time, compute both true and false output, and then select the proper output depending on `when` result.

Comment: @Steven : Would this depend on the size of the data set? My real case is a (very) large data set and I noticed the same behaviour.

Comment: @JohnDoe It is independant of the size.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would advice you to consider that your UDF should apply to the whole dataframe and adapt the code in consequence:

```py
@F.udf
def upperCase(in_string):
    return in_string.upper() if in_string else in_string


df.withColumn(
    "Created_Name",
    upperCase(F.col("Name")),
).show()

+------------+------------+
|        Name|Created_Name|
+------------+------------+
|  John Jones|  JOHN JONES|
|Tracey Smith|TRACEY SMITH|
|        null|        null|
| Amy Sanders| AMY SANDERS|
|            |            |
+------------+------------+
```

---

**NB**: Your UDF works if you filter out the *bad* lines:

```py
df.where(F.col("Name").isNotNull()).select(upperCaseUDF(F.col("Name"))).show()
+--------------+                                                                
|<lambda>(Name)|
+--------------+
|    JOHN JONES|
|  TRACEY SMITH|
|   AMY SANDERS|
|              |
+--------------+
```