# Spark: Using null checking in a CASE WHEN expression to protect against type errors

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have a UDF that compares two strings `str_left` and `str_right`, but fails if either is a null.

I thought it should be possible to 'protect' the udf with a case expression as follows:

```sql
select 
    case 
    when str_left is null or str_right is null then -1 
    else my_udf(str_left, str_right)
    end as my_col
from my_table
```

But this fails in practice. Why does this not work?

Here is a complete example in pyspark, which produces the error `TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len()` in Spark 2.4.3 and Spark 3.1.2.

```py
from pyspark.context import SparkContext
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.types import DoubleType

sc = SparkContext.getOrCreate()
spark = SparkSession(sc)
from pyspark.sql import Row

def rel_length(str1, str2):   
    return len(str1)/len(str2)

spark.udf.register("rel_length_py", rel_length, DoubleType())

rows = [
    {"str_col_l": "a string", "str_col_r": "another string"},
    {"str_col_l": "a string", "str_col_r": None},

]
df = spark.createDataFrame(Row(**x) for x in rows)
df.createOrReplaceTempView("str_comp")

sql = """select 
    case
    when str_col_r is null or str_col_l is null  then -1
    else rel_length_py(str_col_l, str_col_r) 
    end
    as rel
from str_comp
"""
spark.sql(sql).show()
```

I've tried to simplify this down to the reproducible example above.  The 'real world' problem we're encountering is a similar case statement with [this udf](https://github.com/moj-analytical-services/splink_scalaudfs/blob/624182115fcc1efbb267ce3523dc861f92bc320f/src/main/scala/uk/gov/moj/dash/linkage/Similarity.scala#L175). [Here's a gist](https://gist.github.com/RobinL/a201eb65da9cc1ae171ae6359e987a3f) with the code that produces the error.  Strangley, in this more complex example, it fails in spark 3.1.2 but succeeds in 2.4.3.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Applying UDF only on rows where value is not null or not an empty string not working as expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68347679/applying-udf-only-on-rows-where-value-is-not-null-or-not-an-empty-string-not-wor)

Comment: Thanks - that is super helpful.  Your comment on the above is probably the root cause: "I think that the optimizer, in order to save computation time, compute both true and false output, and then select the proper output depending on when result".  Is it possibly to elaborate on that at all e.g. by referencing the source code or some other more detailed explanation?  i.e. how sure are you that this is true?

Comment: I said  `I think` because I'm not totally sure. A lot of system use the same method but it does not crash when facing an error. The problem here is to understand in the code why the error is not caught and ignored. But I did not take the time to read the code and understand the whole mechanic, sorry

Comment: No problem - it's a very useful tip.  I've looked at the code [here](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/9af338cd685bce26abbc2dd4d077bde5068157b1/sql/catalyst/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/catalyst/expressions/conditionalExpressions.scala#L138) but i'm a bit out of my depth. I will do some tests to see if I can verify this behaviour and report back.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In many situations, the Spark optimiser will execute ALL parts of your case expression, even though some appear to be unreachable.

In the example given in the question, we can show that Spark executes BOTH:

```
when str_col_r is null or str_col_l is null  then -1
```

AND

```
else rel_length_py(str_col_l, str_col_r)
```

even in cases where `str_col_r is null` or `str_col_l is null`

Here is some example code.  The dataframe is as follows, where the second row is repeated 100 time.

```
| str_col_l   | str_col_r   |
|:------------|:------------|
| a           | b           |
| a string    | null        |
| a string    | null        |
| a string    | null        |
...96 repeats...
| a string    | null        |
```

I have set:

```
conf.set("spark.sql.shuffle.partitions", "1")
conf.set("spark.default.parallelism", "1")
```

We run a UDF that sleeps for 1 second whenever it is executed:

```py
%%time

def rel_length(str1, str2):   
    time.sleep(1)
    if str1 is None or str2 is None:
        return -0.9

    return len(str1)/len(str2)

spark.udf.register("rel_length_py", rel_length, DoubleType())

rows = [{"str_col_l": "a", "str_col_r": "b"}] +  [{"str_col_l": "a string", "str_col_r": None}]*100

df = spark.createDataFrame(Row(**x) for x in rows)
df.createOrReplaceTempView("str_comp")

sql = """select 
    case
    when str_col_r is null or str_col_l is null  then -1
    else rel_length_py(str_col_l, str_col_r) 
    end
    as rel
from str_comp
"""
spark.sql(sql).toPandas().head(2)
```

```
CPU times: user 183 ms, sys: 61.8 ms, total: 245 ms
Wall time: 1min 46s
```

i.e. around 100 seconds.

Here the sleep statement is repositioned in the UDF so it sleeps for 1 second ONLY for the first row.

```py
%%time

def rel_length(str1, str2):   
    if str1 is None or str2 is None:
        return -0.9
    time.sleep(1)
    return len(str1)/len(str2)

spark.udf.register("rel_length_py", rel_length, DoubleType())

rows = [{"str_col_l": "a", "str_col_r": "b"}] +  [{"str_col_l": "a string", "str_col_r": None}]*100

df = spark.createDataFrame(Row(**x) for x in rows)
df.createOrReplaceTempView("str_comp")

sql = """select 
    case
    when str_col_r is null or str_col_l is null  then -1
    else rel_length_py(str_col_l, str_col_r) 
    end
    as rel
from str_comp
"""
spark.sql(sql).toPandas().head(2)
```

```
CPU times: user 14.5 ms, sys: 6.42 ms, total: 20.9 ms
Wall time: 1.36 s
```

This proves that *at least in some instances* all parts of the case statement will execute.  I don't believe that all parts are *guaranteed* to execute, because I've seen working examples that would error if all parts were being executed.

Answer (score 0):

It's funny that for some reason, spark executes the udf (at least for some rows) even if it does not use the result. Sometimes catalyst manages not to do it, like when the column is generated with `lit(None)` but most of the time it does.

The easiest way to solve this would be to modify your udf to handle that case:

```py
def rel_lenght(str1, str2):
    if str1 is None or str2 is None:
        return -1
    else:
        len(str1) / len(str2)
```